# Agora on-premise video recording on google cloud run

Tags: node.js, udp, google-cloud-storage, google-cloud-run, agora.io

I have a Google Cloud Run instance running Agora On-premise Recording inside it. But I noticed that recorded videos included just sound and black screen (The same environment was fine for the compute engine). Then, I saw Google Cloud Run that supports TCP, not UDP. I think that the problem occurs for this reason. Is there any way to send UDP traffic to Cloud Run Instance?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can't send UDP to Cloud Run services. In addition, Cloud Run accept TCP over HTTP protocol. You can't send non-http TCP traffic to Cloud Run.

Comment: Thanks for the answer